# Linear regression, conditional expectations and expected values

Tags: regression

Okay so just a bit hazy on a few things, any help would be much appreciated. 
It is my understanding that the linear regression model is predicted via a conditional expectation

$$E(Y|X)=b+Xb+e$$

1. Do we assume that both $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with some unknown probability distribution? it was my understanding that only the residuals and the estimated beta coefficients were random variables. if so, as an example, if $Y =$ obesity and $X =$ age, if we take the conditional expectation $E(Y|X=35)$ meaning, whats the expected value of being obese if the individual is $35$ across the sample, would we just take the average(arithmetic mean) of y for those observations where $X=35$? yet doesn't the expected value entail that we must multiply this by the probability of occurring ? but how in that sense to we find the probability of the $X$-value variable occurring if it represent something like age?
2. If $X$ represented something like the exchange rate, would this be classified as random? how on earth would you find the expected value of this without knowing the probability though? or would the expected value just equal the mean in the limit.
3. If we don't assume the dependent variables are themselves random variables,   since we don't obverse the probability, what do we assume they are? just fixed values or something? but if this is the case, how can we condition on a non-random variable to begin with?  what do we assume about the independent  variables distribution?

Sorry if anything doesn't make sense or is obvious to anyone.

Comment: The regression coefficient $\beta$ is an unknown constant, not a random variable (in a frequentist world at least).

Comment: what you mean by conditional expectations? E(Y|X) simply means Y given X, that is, expected value of Y at X. Say, y = 5 + x, then you E(Y|X = 5) is 10. I did not get your point with conditional expectation

Comment: @RichardHardy, it was my understanding that since B is the mean of the of the sampling distribution of of the beta's, that it is a random variable characterised by a normal distribution. are you referring to the population model?

Comment: Yes, population model.

Comment: @WilliamCarulli Richard is referring to the difference between a *population* parameter and an estimated parameter.  The estimated parameter is indeed a random variable, but the (unknown) true population parameter is a fixed value.

Comment: @MatthewDrury How is the estimated parameter a random variable in a frequentist setting? Richard Hardy is right, it is a fixed estimate, not a r.v.

Comment: WilliamCarulli as @RichardHardy said, in frequentist estimation what you get a is fixed value and not a random variable. Estimating/approximating probability distributions (r.v.) instead of fixed values is the Bayesian approach.

Comment: @Digio, the estimate is a realization of an estimator. The latter is a function of a random sample and therefore a random variable. People loosely call estimate a random variable but to be correct, it is a realization of a random variable.

Comment: @RichardHardy Am I wrong to believe that the frequentist approach derives estimators using MLE, which are themselves r.v. but their realization is a plain number? [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/317541/why-is-an-estimator-considered-a-random-variable) would support my view. Based on this idea, the observed coefficients of a regression model should be seen as fixed numbers, not r.v.

Comment: @Digio, Yes, the realization of a random variable is a plain number; this is what I intended to convey in my last comment. Matthew used imprecise language but I believe his idea is correct (once you note that a realization of a random variable is no longer a random variable itself).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the probability model underlying linear regression, X and Y *are* random variables.

> if so, as an example, if Y = obesity and X = age, if we take the conditional expectation E(Y|X=35) meaning, whats the expected value of being obese if the individual is 35 across the sample, would we just take the average(arithmetic mean) of y for those observations where X=35?

That's right.  In general, you cannot expect that you will have enough data at each specific value of X, or it may be impossible to do so if X can take a continuous range of values.  But conceptually, this is correct.

> yet doesn't the expected value entail that we must multiply this by the probability of occurring ?

This is the difference between the *unconditional* expectation $E[Y]$ and the *conditional* expectation $E[Y \mid X = x]$.  The relationship between them is

$$ E[Y] = \sum_x E[Y \mid X = x] Pr[X = x] $$

which is the law of total expectation.

> but how in that sense to we find the probability of the X-value variable occurring if it represent something like age?

Generally you don't in linear regression.  Since we are attempting to determine $E[Y \mid X]$, we don't need to know $Pr[X = x]$.

> If we don't assume the independent variables are themselves random variables, since we don't obverse the probability, what do we assume they are? just fixed values or something?

We *do* assume that Y is a random variable.  One way to think about linear regression is as a probability model for $Y$

$$ Y \sim X \beta + N(0, \sigma) $$

Which says that, once you know the value of X, the random variation in Y is confined to the summand $N(0, \sigma)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, helped me out immensely. cheers.

Comment: @WilliamCarulli You're welcome!  Feel free to ask any follow up questions and I'll do my best to answer.  If I really cleared up all your issues, you can accept it as well.

Comment: This is a fine post.  However, I think that any answer that does not acknowledge that $X$ (a) can be fixed or (b) may be a random variable (with particular independence assumptions) is not really addressing the concerns expressed in the question.

Comment: @MatthewDrury, Just to clarify, if my dependent variable is say the exchange rate, and my dependant is the domestic interest rate, then

Comment: @MatthewDrury@MatthewDrury, Just to clarify, if my dependent variable is say the exchange rate, and my dependant is the domestic interest rate, then E(E(exchange rate|interest rate) ) = E(exchange rate) = the sample mean of exchange rate? I guess what is confusing me is that I always assume expectations are calculated based off probabilities, I don't see the reason for denoting linear regression as a conditional expectation when solving it via matrix algebra seems much different then taking the overall expectation.

Comment: @MatthewDrury is the conditional expectation more of just a formality? since in essence we don't observe the probability distribution of the independent variable for something like the interest rate. so the expected value of the independent variable is just the mean?

Comment: @WilliamCarulli there's more than one way to compute a conditional expectation. That's the beauty of math: integrating $x f(x)$ in general is hard or impossible, but if you make certain assumptions about $x$ and $f(x)$, then you can find other, equivalent ways to perform the computation. It's not a formality; it's an equivalence.

Comment: The expected value of the independent variable is whatever you model it to be. The point is that _the marginal distribution of the independent variable doesn't enter into the model at all_. There's a very clear and simple proof posted [here](http://thestatsgeek.com/2013/08/30/why-regression-inference-assuming-fixed-predictors-is-still-valid-for-random-predictors/)

Answer (score 5):

There will be a LOT of answers to this question, but I still want to add one since you made some interesting points. For simplicity I only consider the simple linear model.

```
   It is my understanding that the linear regression model
   is predicted via a conditional expectation E(Y|X)=b+Xb+e
```

The fundamental equation of a simple linear regression analysis is:
$$\mathbb E(Y\,|\,X) = \beta_0 +\beta_1X,$$
This equation meaning is that the average value of $Y$ is linear on the values of $X$. One can also notice that the expected value is also linear on the parameters $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$, which is why the model is called linear. This fundamental equation can be rewritten as:
$$Y = \beta_0+\beta_1X+\epsilon,$$
where $\epsilon$ is a random variable with mean zero: $\mathbb E(\epsilon) = 0$

```
Do we assume that both X and Y are Random variables with some unknown 
probability distribution? ... If we don't assume the independent variables 
are themselves random
```

The independent variable $X$ can be random or fixed. The dependent variable $Y$ is ALWAYS random.

Usually one assumes that $\{X_1,...,X_n\}$ are fixed numbers. This is because regression analysis was developed and is vastly applied in the context of designed experiments, where the $X$'s values are previously fixed.

The formulas for the least squares estimates of $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ are the same even if the $X$'s are assumed random, but the distribution of these estimates will generally not be the same compared to the situation with fixed $X$'s.

```
if we take the conditional expectation E(Y|X=35) ... would we just take 
the average(arithmetic mean) of y for those observations where X=35?
```

In the simple linear model you can build a estimate $\hat\varphi(x)$ of $\mathbb E(Y|X = x)$ based on the estimates of $\hat \beta_0$ and $\hat \beta_1$, namely:
$$\hat\varphi(x) = \hat\beta_0+\hat\beta_1x$$
The conditional mean least squared estimator has expression equal to the one you described if your model treats the different weights as levels of a single factor. Those models are also known as one-way ANOVA, which is a particular case of (not simple) linear model.

Comment: Some of the remarks in this post are unusual and might be misunderstood. First, the model is called "linear" because it is linear in the *parameters*, not in $X$. Second, the estimates $\hat\beta_0$ and $\hat\beta_1$ are random variables regardless of what is assumed about $X$.  Third, your treatment of conditional expectation appears to confound the *observations* with the *true conditional distribution.* Finally, the reference to "no repeated values" is confusing because it is irrelevant.

Comment: @whuber "First, the model is called "linear" because it is linear in the parameters" I was explaining the  equation meaning, not the meaning of "linear" in "linear model". "the estimates β̂ 0 and β̂ 1 are random variables regardless of what is assumed about X" surely, but the distribution of those random variables change depending on the way you treat X.

Comment: @whuber I totally agree with your last points. I'm going to edit my answer so it is clearer in all the issues you pointed. Thanks for the feedback.