# Is the variance of an estimator a random-variable?

Tags: variance, random-variable, estimators

Is the variance of an estimator a random-variable?

If so, the mean of the variance and the variance of the variance exist.

An estimator of the variance of this variance of an estimator also exists.

Comment: Do you mean the *empirical variance* of an estimator, which itself is an estimator and hence a random variable?

Comment: An estimator is a [random variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/317541/why-is-an-estimator-considered-a-random-variable).  The variance of a random variable, by definition, is a *number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the variance of an estimator a random-variable?

The (population) variance of any random variable, including an estimator $T$ of a population parameter $\theta$, is not a random variable. From the definition,

$$\operatorname{Var}[T] \triangleq \mathbb{E}[(T-\mathbb{E}[T])^2] \triangleq\int_{\Omega} (T - \mathbb{E}[T])^2\ dF(T)$$

you are averaging across all possible instances of $T$. This leaves you with a scalar.

---

> If so, the mean of the variance and the variance of the variance exist.

As above, it isn't so.

---

> An estimator of the variance of this variance of an estimator also exists.

If the population variance $\operatorname{Var}[T]$ exists, then you could come up with an estimator $Q$ to estimate it.

But then you might think that you want $\operatorname{Var}[Q]$... But then how to estimate that? Welcome to [Siphonaptera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siphonaptera_(poem)):

> Great fleas have little fleas upon their backs to bite 'em,
> And little fleas have lesser fleas, and so ad infinitum.
> And the great fleas themselves, in turn, have greater fleas to go on;
> While these again have greater still, and greater still, and so on.
> -- Augustus De Morgan

Or perhaps even more apt is [*It's turtles all the way down*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down).